# How can I get Fiddler to watch traffic through CNTLM

Tags: fiddler, ntlm, cntlm

EDIT: I don't know what I did before but it seems to work ok now. I'm not seeng traffic form TortoiseHg but that's no major loss. Traffic from the browser is fine.

I've voted to close this question.

```
I'm behind an ISA server so I'm using CNTLM to purxy-auth clients like Git, Mercurial & even Chrome. I know Fiddler can do this too but CNTLM is much faster for Git, Hg etc. There are usually 2x 407's before the 200 goes through in Fiddler.

Fiddler ignores 127.0.0.* which is a bummer because that's where CNTLM is. How can I get it to capture this traffic?
```

Comment: Fiddler doesn't *ignore* anything, so it's not entirely clear what you're asking for. Can you please be more specific about what isn't working, and what you're hoping to do with Fiddler?

Comment: I think I stuffed up. Edited the question to confess my dumb. Thanks for following up.

Comment: I just figured this out, and made a blog post scheduled for next year (: Not to want to leave you in the dark though: add this line to your `cntlm.ini` so that it knows it should forward traffic to Fiddler: `Proxy  127.0.0.1:8888`